# Error after adding addons from GitHub to Blender

Tags: blender, add-on

Like this type of error:

[image]

I will try to make a 3d home but the addons are not working.
I uninstall and then reinstall the app but still stuck. Also watch YouTube but nothing happened.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. There is a separate site for [blender.se] questions.

Comment: Can you show what output the console is throwing?